# Php Pm System inbox/outbox together (facebook style)

Tags: php, mysql, message, messaging

I try to make a page showing latest pm from each user, like in facebook, all sent and recieved messages in same page.

I dont want to split message page with recieved and sent tabs.

I build this query but got stucked, and cant go further.

```
SELECT pm_id,  message, unread, time_sent, from_id, to_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT from_id) FROM pm WHERE to_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] AND recipient_delete = "0") as pm_count
    FROM   (SELECT *
            FROM pm
            ORDER BY time_sent DESC) as temp
    WHERE (to_id = $_SESSION['user_id']   AND recipient_delete = "0")
    OR ( from_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] AND sender_delete = "0") 
    GROUP BY from_id, to_id
    ORDER BY time_sent desc
```

With this I get duplicate posts between users like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vexd.png).

Comment: I cannot see a real duplicate the one is from admin to user, the other is from user to admin, even the time is different? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: no you are right, but i try to display only one latest message between admin and user